# different between call view by name or use binding in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

i'am a newest in android kotlin

I want to know what is the difference between the two lines of code below and which one is better to use

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMaindinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    bindins = DataBindingutil.setContentview( this, R.layout.activity_main)


        textview.text="text"//or

        binding.textview.text="text"
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** There are a few ways of getting views - using view binding is the currently recommended method.

**View Binding (recommended)**

The recommended way of accessing views is to use view binding. It offers a few advantages over getting the views manually

- Less boilerplate code (you don't need to write a bunch of `findViewById` calls)
- Null safety (catches errors like trying to access views from the wrong layout at build time instead of run time)
- Type safety - the type of each view is set to help avoid invalid casts

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        // or, without using DataBindingUtil
        // binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        // setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.textview.text="text"
    }
}
```

**Manually Getting Views**

The old way also still works - you can always call `findViewById` yourself. Keep in mind that it may error or return null if the view is not found or if you try to cast it to the wrong type.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        val textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)
        textview.text="text"
    }
}
```

**Kotlin Synthetics (deprecated)**

Kotlin synthetics were introduced in 2017 to make it easier to get views, but are now deprecated and [should be replaced with view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration). With synthetics you would have an import with your layout file name, then you could just access views from it directly.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        textview.text="text"
    }
}
```