# Not getting my ID's from my XML File into my Kotlin file

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So, I'm new to this and I'd really appreciate a quick help. I'm making a chat app for android and my ID's ive given to EditText arent't being referenced into my Kotlin file. When I type them in, they aren't shown on the suggestion drop down and they have that yellow squiggle that says 'Parameter Not Used'. Here's the code from my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chat"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_background"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_background"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:background="@drawable/edt_background"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's what i'm trying to do on my Kotlin file:

```
package com.example.chatapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var edtEmail: EditText
    private lateinit var edtPassword: EditText
    private lateinit var btn_login: Button
    private lateinit var btn_signup: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

Really appreciate some help on this. I'm on the latest Chipmunk update. Thanks!

Comment: no need to define these variables, you can access them directly!!
check this link for more info-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811889/4604095

Comment: The ID you give in the xml is totally unrelated to the names of variables you declare in the actual app code. In order to assign a view to the variable (which can be named whatever you want) you need to use something like view binding or call `myvar = findViewById(R.id.name_from_xml)`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149674/different-between-call-view-by-name-or-use-binding-in-android/72155635#72155635) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to define those variables, one of them would be [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), which is a part of android jetpack and is pretty popular now. Different (and easier to implement I guess) option is by using "findViewById()" which would look like this:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/my_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

```
// the <Button> part won't be necessary if you have already declared a lateinit variable before, like you did
// also, I would advise to put this code inside the "onCreate" function ;)
val myButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.my_button)
```

more on that [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)